# Icons from react-icons with classes name instead of component

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome, react-icons

Is there a way in React Icons to specify my icons as a string, for example for the class name?

Currently I am using a React UI library which requires the names of the icons to be passed as their classes.

I know that you can use icons using react-icons as follows:

```tsx
<FaArrowLeft/>
```

However, I would need the following icon name: "fa-arrow-left".

Is there any way I can get the class name instead of using the component?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used React Icons specifically but I've gotten the result you are after by using bootstrap and font-awesome.
Install bootstrap and font-awesome in you project.

```
yarn add bootstrap
yarn add font-awesome
```

Or

```
   npm install bootstrap
   npm install font-awesome
```

Import them (I import to my index.js file but where ever is the root of your app)

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css';
```

Then you can use class names like

```
'fa fa-sm fa-eye'
```

for example to get a small eye icon.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which library you are using, but I'm assuming it's 'react-icons/fa'. It is possible to use it by string but after you import them all which might effect your bundle size by ~30MB extra which is not small size.
Here is an example how to do it with custom component:

```
 import * as Icons from "react-icons/fa";
    
    const CustomFaIcon = ({ name }) => {
      const FaIcon = Icons[name];
      if (!FaIcon) return <p>Icon not found!</p>;
    
      return <FaIcon />;
    };
    
    export default function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <CustomFaIcon name="Your String" />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

I also suggest that you check out react-fontawesome library, you might end up with lower bundle size if you use it corrently, here you can find some examples how to do it:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome/blob/master/examples/create-react-app-typescript/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

I create file utils.js and added this code:

```
import React from 'react';

import * as ai from "react-icons/ai";
import * as bi from "react-icons/bi";
import * as bs from "react-icons/bs";
import * as cg from "react-icons/cg";
import * as ci from "react-icons/ci";
import * as di from "react-icons/di"
import * as fa from "react-icons/fa"
import * as fa6 from "react-icons/fa6"
import * as fc from "react-icons/fc"
import * as fi from "react-icons/fi"
import * as gi from "react-icons/gi"
import * as go from "react-icons/go"
import * as gr from "react-icons/gr"
import * as hi from "react-icons/hi"
import * as hi2 from "react-icons/hi2"
import * as im from "react-icons/im"
import * as io from "react-icons/io"
import * as io5 from "react-icons/io5"
import * as lia from "react-icons/lia"
import * as lu from "react-icons/lu"
import * as md from "react-icons/md"
import * as pi from "react-icons/pi"
import * as ri from "react-icons/ri"
import * as rx from "react-icons/rx"
import * as si from "react-icons/si"
import * as sl from "react-icons/sl"
import * as tb from "react-icons/tb"
import * as tfi from "react-icons/tfi"
import * as ti from "react-icons/ti"
import * as vsc from "react-icons/vsc"
import * as wi from "react-icons/wi"

const libs = {
    "ai":ai,
    "bi":bi,
    "bs":bs,
    "cg":cg,
    "ci":ci,
    "di":di,
    "fa":fa,
    "fa6":fa6,
    "fc":fc,
    "fi":fi,
    "gi":gi,
    "go":go,
    "gr":gr,
    "hi":hi,
    "hi2":hi2,
    "im":im,
    "io":io,
    "io5":io5,
    "lia":lia,
    "lu":lu,
    "md":md,
    "pi":pi,
    "ri":ri,
    "rx":rx,
    "si":si,
    "sl":sl,
    "tb":tb,
    "tfi":tfi,
    "ti":ti,
    "vsc":vsc,
    "wi":wi,
};

const GetIcon = ({lib, name}) => {
    const lib_ = libs[lib];
    console.log(lib_)
    if (!lib_) throw Error(`lib ${lib} - Not found`);
    const Icon = lib_[name];
    console.log(Icon)
    if (!Icon) throw Error(`Icon ${lib} ${name} - Not found`);
    return < Icon />;
};

export default GetIcon;
```

I use it so:

```
import React from 'react';
import GetIcon from "./utils"
    const app = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                < GetIcon lib="bi" name="BiLockAlt" />
            </div>
        );
    };

export default app;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).